# Again with JPA not making sense

Tags: database, jpa

I [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167193/jpa-and-2-simple-tables) earlier and was told to look at mapped by.

> I have 2 tables: A s_id(key) name cli type
>
> ```
> B sa_id(key) s_id user pwd.
> ```
>
> So in Jpa I have:
>
> ```
> @Entity class A...{
> @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
> @JoinTable( name="A_B",
> joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id",
> table="a",unique=false)},
> inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id",
> table="b", unique=true)} ) Collection
> getB(){...} }
> ```
>
> class b is just a basic entity class
>   with no reference to A.
>
> Hopefully that is clear. My question
>   is: Do I really need a join table to
>   do such a simple join? Can't this be
>   done with a simple joincolumn or
>   something?

So now if Have this, but jpa is trying to write the query with some new column that doesn't exist (`s_s_id`)

```
@Entity
class A{
...
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="s")
Collection<B> x;
}

@Entity
class B{
@ManyToOne
A s;
}

With these tables:
A 
s_id(key) name cli type

B
sa_id(key) s_id(the keys from A) user pwd.
```

How can I do the `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` joins such that I don't need a new column nor a new table?  Please give me an example.  Is the issue the lack of a foreign key in the B table?

If I leave out the mapped by I get `Unknown column 't1.S_S_ID' in 'field list'`

If I put in the mapped by I get `Unknown column 'S_S_ID' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

I found it, I need to add the `@JoinColumn` and give it a name...